# Array unshift for string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, for-loop

```
var hello = 'hello';
Array.prototype.unshift.call(hello, '11') // gives error
Array.prototype.join.call(hello, ', ') // works, why??
```

can someone explain to me why *.join* works and why *.unshift* doesn't

Comment: What did you expect that to do anyway?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because strings are immutable, and `unshift` tries to assign to an index (property) of the string, as in

```
"hello"[4] = '1'
```

Reference: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-string-exotic-objects:

> A String object is an exotic object that encapsulates a String value and exposes virtual integer indexed data properties corresponding to the individual code unit elements of the String value. Exotic String objects always have a data property named "length" whose value is the number of code unit elements in the encapsulated String value. **Both the code unit data properties and the "length" property are non-writable and non-configurable.**

`join` doesn't assign anything and only reads properties, therefore it works with any object that has `.length`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
String.prototype.unshift = function(ch) {
    return ch + this;
}

var s = "BCD";
s = s.unshift("A");

console.log(s); // ABCD
```

Comment: Why use an array, then `.unshift()`, then `.join()`? All the code does is concatenate two strings, so `return el + this` is enough. `return el.concat(this)` if you really want to do it using method calls. With that said, it doesn't actually answer the *why?* question. Just offers a completely different alternative.