# What kind of element in that array? How it calls and where i can learn more about it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, element

That's my first own question on StackOwerflow.

My problem in JavaScript's arrays is:

```
var arr=[];
arr[0] = 'a';
arr[1] = 'b';
arr['2']='c';
arr['x']='d';
arr.y='e';
console.log(arr);
```

```
[ 'a', 'b', 'c', x: 'd', y: 'e' ] -- this is what i get
```

And i do not understand what is that actually:

```
arr['2']='c';
arr['x']='d';
arr.y='e';
```

I did not expected that behaviour because i've not seen that examples and theory before

Comment: maybe you can read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67030137/why-does-an-array-allow-a-string-as-an-index-in-javascript

Comment: @Damzaky Thank you!!! Didn't found it before :)

Comment: The OP created exactly 3 valid array-**items**. The indices are `0`, `1` and `'2'` with the first two being integer number-values and the latter being a string which represents another valid array index. Thus the OP's array features a `length` value of `3`. All other assignments just add additional **properties**, like `x` and `y` to the OP's array. Thus they are not recognized as iterable array-items.

Comment: @OksanaSmirnova ... _" Didn't found it before :)"_ ... really ?.. [MDN documentation - array indices](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#array_indices)